# Rails: can not insert element to array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Model

```
Material
User
Materials_Users(Join table)
```

In console, when I try `material.user_ids = [1,2]` , it works well. But when I try to insert element one by one, like `material.user_ids << 3` , it does not work, the array turn to empty and nothing is inserted into the array.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't have enough information to help. You should describe in more detail what you are doing. How exactly are you inserting elements one by one? Did you initialize the `material.user_ids` before appending with `<<`? What do you mean by "it does not work"? How exactly did you diagnose this? Many things could have gone wrong, so being specific is important. For example, add an excerpt from what you did on the Rails console. Also, please improve your writing. It is riddled with errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the shovel method only works for objects. Do this instead.

```
material.users << user
```

Read here for other ways of adding associations - http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference